# RDLC parameters filter after records pulled

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to determine best practices with client-side reporting using the reportviewer displaying an RDLC.  When designing a report, you can specify parameters to pass to the report which can be used to filter the records.  Using SQL Profiler, however, when running the report it appears that the filter is applied after the records are pulled down for the report.  Am I seeing this correctly?

If so, why isn't this kind of thing discouraged?  Shouldn't the records be filtered perhaps at the dataset level or at some point such that the records are filtered prior to being sent to the client (for performance reasons, of course)?  I have looked and looked for a discussion of these kinds of issues over the internet and all I see is a multitude of ways to implement parameters (ie, how to) but no discussion of when one way is better than another and why.  This isn't anything new, so I would expect there to be more about this out there.  Can anyone point me to something that discusses this if I have missed something?

Comment: Not sure what discussion your are looking for. Reporting services always apply filters after the dataset is fetched. This is because the same dataset can be used in several controls with different filter/sort/grouping in the same report. It is also not an easy task to convert a filter/sort/grouping specified in (maybe third-part-) controls to something which work with the dataset provider. You can't just append a WHERE clause at the end. If you want to filter the fetched dataset you need to add parameters to the query.

Comment: Well, in that the potential performance gotcha is not obvious, I would expect there to be more advice out there to avoid using parameters for filtering in the report itself.  I come from a world where query performance is typically a part of any discussion in the use of a reporting technology.  In many examples of the reportviewer, however, I've noticed that parameters are a "by the way" type item or an not even mentioned, but the reality is that parameterization is usually a big part of making reporting more flexible and powerful.  If it needs to be done beforehand, it's not hard to say so.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with client side RDLC recently and came to the conclusion that the data handling is too inefficient. Like you point out, I encountered the issues with parameters not filtering as you'd expect. I used crystal reports (on which I think this is based) nearly 10 years ago and I'm sure there wasn't issues like this.

The best method I used was to pre-prepare your dataset before generating the report. I found always passing the data at runtime, not defining data access in the report definition ensures it will only ever use the data you provide.

You are right, there's very little documentation/discussion on using this, ultimately I ended up removing it from my project and using other methods to render the charts/tables etc.